Timefold context propagation during solving
I am using Timefold 1.15 and Quarkus 3.1
I am trying to save the data during solving of the timetable
but I have some contexts that's required during solve, tenant context for row security and identity context
but I am facing issues related to unavailability of the contexts
Sample code:
  solverManager.solveBuilder()
            .withProblemId(finalRequestId)
            .withProblemFinder((id) -> timeTableJob.get(finalRequestId).timetable)
            .withBestSolutionConsumer(bestSolution -> timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId, Job.ofTimetable(bestSolution)))
            .withFinalBestSolutionConsumer(solution -> {
                timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId,Job.ofTimetable(solution));
                plannedLessonRepository.save(solution);
            })
            .withExceptionHandler((id, exception) -> {
                timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId, Job.ofException(exception));
                LOGGER.error("Failed solving jobId ({}).", finalRequestId, exception);
            })
            .run();

Error:
2024-11-26 17:18:32,463 ERROR [org.acm.sch.res.TimeTableResource] (pool-13-thread-1) Failed solving jobId (101).: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getTenantId(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:292)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:193)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.(SessionImpl.java:230)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1381)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1247)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.JTASessionOpener.openSession(JTASessionOpener.java:46)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:92)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.find(TransactionScopedSession.java:175)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.find(SessionLazyDelegator.java:825)
at org.hibernate.Session_OpdLahisOZ9nWRPXMsEFQmQU03A_Synthetic_ClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.findById(AbstractJpaOperations.java:183)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository.findById(PlannedLessonRepository.java)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository.findById(PlannedLessonRepository.java)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository.save(PlannedLessonRepository.java:24)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository_Subclass.save$$superforward(Unknown Source)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:136)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:61)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository_Subclass.save(Unknown Source)
at org.acme.timetable.persistence.PlannedLessonRepository_ClientProxy.save(Unknown Source)
at org.acme.timetable.rest.TimeTableResource.lambda$solve$2(TimeTableResource.java:112)
at ai.timefold.solver.core.impl.solver.ConsumerSupport.lambda$consumeFinalBestSolution$1(ConsumerSupport.java:102)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

The best solution consumer, final best solution consumer, and exception handler are run in a different thread than the one accepting the API call. As a result, the transaction's context is not propagated.
What you can do is use QuarkusTransaction to start and end the transaction in the final best solution consumer (and remove the @Transactional annotation).
  solverManager.solveBuilder()
            .withProblemId(finalRequestId)
            .withProblemFinder((id) -> timeTableJob.get(finalRequestId).timetable)
            .withBestSolutionConsumer(bestSolution -> timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId, Job.ofTimetable(bestSolution)))
            .withFinalBestSolutionConsumer(solution -> {
                QuarkusTransaction.joiningExisting().run(() -> {
                    timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId,Job.ofTimetable(solution));
                    plannedLessonRepository.save(solution);
                });
            })
            .withExceptionHandler((id, exception) -> {
                timeTableJob.put(finalRequestId, Job.ofException(exception));
                LOGGER.error("Failed solving jobId ({}).", finalRequestId, exception);
            })
            .run();


Thanks for your answer, it worked with me after I added ActivateRequestContext to the repository and removed Transactional
